# I have problem with modal dialog css and angular 5

Tags: css, angular, modal-dialog, angular5, alert

I have problem with modal dialog. when the modal dialog appears, why the element behind the modal still appears like the form and button can still be clicked. it should be when the modal appears the element behind it cannot be clicked right?

here is the HTML:

```
<app-dialog [(visible)]="testingModal">
<div class="alert">
  <img class="gagal" src="assets/images/i-clear.png">
  <div class="msg-info">yeyeye lalalla</div>
</div>
<a 
  href="javascript:void(0);" 
  (click)="closeModal()" 
  class="btn-dialog-ok">
  CLOSE
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 999;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.dialog {
  z-index: 3000;
  width: 32%;
  height: auto !important;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 12% auto;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #444;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a working snippet so we can figure out whats wrong? Maybe a jsfiddle, codepen or snippet here?

Comment: I just want to know the css script to disable the element behind the modal dialog, is there?, Thank You. Because the script is to many.

Comment: Where is your overlay? Where is your dialog? whose style you've posted. I can't see that